# Optimize Lisp recursive random walk

Tags: recursion, optimization, lisp, clisp

This function results in stack overflow for more than about 2000 steps, is there any way I can easily optimize it to use less memory?

```
(defun randomwalk (steps state)
(displaystate state)
(if (equal steps 0) nil
        (if (solved? state) t
            (let ((nrmlstate (normalize state)))
                (randomwalk (- steps 1) (applymove nrmlstate (nth (random 
(length (getallmoves nrmlstate))) (getallmoves nrmlstate))))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: You might want to improve your question with better code formatting and a reproducible test case. See this Stackoverflow help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: As Rainer says, the formatting of your code is so bad that it's hard to see what it does (and the lack of a test case also does not help), but in most implementations (but *not* guaranteed by the language) compiling this function should result in a process which does not consume stack. (Some implementations may not need the compilation step, even.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you only call in tail position which means you can easily rewrite it to not recurse at all:

```lisp
(defun randomwalk (steps state)
  (loop :if (= steps 0)     
            :do (return nil)
        :if (solved? state) 
            :do (return t)
        :else
            :do (let* ((nrmlstate (normalize state))
                       (moves (getallmoves nrmlstate))
                       (random-move (nth (random (length moves)) moves)))
                  (setf state (applymove nrmlstate random-move))
                  (decf steps))))
```

Since I don't have the functions you use I have not been able to test it other than for the base cases.

Comment: I was hoping to keep it purely functional, but this works! I'm stuck with gnu clisp and as far as I can there isn't a way to increase the memory limit or make clisp do tail recursion optimization.

Comment: @RossGriebenow I think Clisp has tail call optimization so if you compile the function you will no longer get stack overflow, however since the Common Lisp standard does not require implementations to do this and even consider any optimization hints in the standard you cannot depend on them in a portable application. Thus idiomatic way to do functional programming in CL is by linear update. This way it's ok to mutate internally as long as the interface is functional.

Comment: @RossGriebenow BTW Increasing stack size is system dependent, but the CLISP FAQ has [stack increasing solutions for both unix and windows](https://clisp.sourceforge.io/impnotes/faq.html#faq-stack) for recursions that cannot be compiled or rewritten.